# El Capitan - no photos?

Tags: macos, photos.app

Just tried to access my photos after upgrading to El Capitan - no luck there.
Looks like Photos won't load any photos - it starts with an empty window, when trying by clicking library I have the same effect...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you turn of wifi and reboot, what happens to photos? Any messages in console app once you open that app after the reboot?

Comment: 10/10/2015 22:17:29.516 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Photos.12062) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Photos.app

Comment: that info is repeated 3 times when starting Photos

Comment: I hope that is the end. After another restart suddenly my Photos started to work properly.